# issue with carousel image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, image-gallery

I am making a simple carousel image gallery. Currently I have two images and I would like the gallery to loop back to the first image after the last and I cannot figure out how to get this functionality working plus my previous and next button have stopped working for some reason.  My jq/js skills are lacking and would appreciate any help to get this working. Here is my jsfiddle of my code    [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/kGAxa/39/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery("#gallery").length) {
        // declare variables
        var totalImages = jQuery("#gallery > li").length,
            imageWidth = jQuery("#gallery > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery("#gallery-wrapper").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function () {
            if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")) {
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({
                    left: "+=" + imageWidth + "px"
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function () {
            if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")) {
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({
                    left: "-=" + imageWidth + "px"
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your fiddle, javascript works well, only css is missing the following attributes:

```css
#gallery-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#gallery {
    position:absolute;
}
```

And the code also needs to be executed within

```js
$(window).load();
```

instead of [$(document).ready();](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/) event handler to work correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/kGAxa/42/

Comment: Thanks for the response and help  Stano! I was wondering how can I have the gallery return to the first slide  or loop back to the first slide after the second. I guess basically making it a continuous slide gallery? thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Stano Thank you so much! appreciate the response and help.It works great in FF but in chrome when I am on the second slide and click the next arrow it doesn't send me back to the first image like it does in ff. not sure why it works in ff and not the same in chrome? any ideas? I really appreciate the help Stano! thank you

Comment: Thank you Joe, if it's possible try also look for some [carousel plugin](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html), should have many possible compatibility bugs fixed. Thank you and have a good time too!